# APIM named values create/update through powershell/cli

Tags: apim

is there a way we can create or update apim named values through power-shell or azure cli.
i tried searching the Microsoft documents i was not able to get anything related. 
is there any command let , im trying to create new named values or update existing named values through power-shell or azure cli

Answer (score 0):

As far as a quick research told me, there is no idiomatic Azure CLI command to do this at the moment.

However, you can achieve the same result using the `az rest` command:

```
az rest \
  --method put \
  --uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION/resourceGroups/$RESOURCE_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/$APIM/namedValues/$NAME?api-version=2019-12-01 \
  --body '{"properties":{"displayName":"$DISPLAYNAME","value": "$VALUE","secret":$SECRET_BOOLEAN}}'
```

Replace the `$CURRENT_SUBSCRIPTION, $RESOURCE_GROUP, $APIM, $NAME, $DISPLAYNAME, $VALUE, $SECRET_BOOLEAN` with your values or PowerShell variables.